# Storing a serializable object in the session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object that I store in the session, something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class GoyaAppUserServerSession
{
   public int TheInt{ get; set; }
   public string TheString{ get; set; }
   public byte TheByte{ get; set; }

   public void SomeMethod() { ... }
   public void SomeOtherMethod() { ... }
}
```

My server session has 3 values and 2 methods. When the object is serialized and deserialized, does the serialization only apply to the values, in which case it's negligible, or is the code that's inside the methods also serialized as a string?

Comment: No, serialization only stores the values. Why would you like to serialize method body?!

Comment: De/Serialization is always just about values. But you can deserialize back into a class of the same type and methods will be already there.

Comment: Serialization is meant to convert data into a stream that can be transmitted/transformed later. So it involves only data manipulation. I wonder what you want to achieve by serializing the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the values; since methods are a compiled definition of the class, there is no reason to store these; therefore it only stores the values of the properties.  Depending on what you are serializing with, it usually uses the properties as the names of the fields during the serialization process.  For instance, if you use XML, it would use the property name as attribute or element, and the value as the inner content.